# MongoDB: Find a document that has all fields and value (except _id) equals of given documents?

Tags: mongodb, filter, find, field, database

Is there a way to search for documents whose all fields and values (except _id) are contained in given document fields?

Example:

```
{_id:..., "field1" : 2 , "field2" : 3}
{_id:..., "field1" : 2 , "field2" : 4}
{_id:..., "field1" : 2 , "field3" : 1}
```

document to place in the query:

```
{"field1" : 2 , "field2" : 4, "field3" : 1}
```

expected result:

```
{_id:..., "field1" : 2 , "field2" : 4}
{_id:..., "field1" : 2 , "field3" : 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
db.numbers.find({ $or: [ {"field1" : 2 , "field2" : 4}, {"field1" : 2 , "field3" : 1} ]})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is :

```
db.yourdb.find({$and : [ {$or : [{"field1" :2}, {"field1" : {$exists : false}}]},  {$or : [{"field2" :4}, {"field2": {$exists : false}}]},{$or : [{"field3" :q}, {"field3": {$exists : false}}]}]})
```